# Linux shell script - How to switch user and run a script?

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sudo, su

I'm currently writing a .sh script to deploy different applications on 4 different machines. Right now I'm having trouble with running a script as another user. I need to log in with myUser with my credentials and then sudo su to user2 to run a specific script.

Normally, I would manually do the following:

```
ssh myUser@remotehost
[Type in password]
sudo su - user2
cd /path/only/accessible/to/user2
./someScript.sh
```

when I tried

`ssh -t myUser@$remotehost "sudo su - user2 && /path/only/accessible/to/user2 && ./someScript.sh"`

I was asked my password, then stayed logged as user2, without any feedback from the script, which would normally give me some informations.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. don't use in `sudo su` - or `sudo` or `su`, but not both together. 2. in `ssh` you forget to do `cd`, why not run script directly(without `cd`), i.e. `"sudo su - user2 && /path/only/accessible/to/user2/someScript.sh"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try
`ssh -t myUser@$remotehost "sudo -u user2 /path/only/accessible/to/user2/someScript.sh"`

If you need shell access after that you can use
`ssh -t myUser@$remotehost "sudo -u user2 /path/only/accessible/to/user2/someScript.sh && /bin/bash -l"`

Comment: why `sudo su`? don't you think its something wrong? its a bad practice.

Comment: Edited (used `sudo su` as in question from Anthony). Now answer without it

Comment: Would have worked but I don't have the rights to execute as user2 on that machine (which is weird, but eh), only to switch user. I'll still mark your answer as accepted for the learning experience. Thanks! The rest of my fight will be with the sysadmin

Answer (score 0):

An update if anyone wonders about this.

What I finally did was to log in with an ssh key. My sysadmin had to get involved in order to set it up, but at least it is a viable option.

```
ssh -i /path/to/sshKey user2@$remoteHost "/path/only/accessible/to/user2/someScript.sh"
```